# Use Web Animations API to expand div height 0 --> 'auto'

Tags: web-animations

I'm trying to get my head around the [web animations standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) and their [polyfill](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js), as I saw it work nicely in the Angular animations library (you set an animation end value to '*' and this becomes 100% of the div size, but that uses a special Angular Animations DSL).

I thought I would start with something simple, so all I want to do is expand a div from 0 height to 'auto'.  i know there are thousands of other ways to do this, but I was trying to use web-animations-js with this code

The code below (which resembles an [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API)) causes the div to expand directly to 'auto' but after a 1 second delay, whereas I want it smoothly to expand.

```
let formDiv = document.querySelector("#new-present-form");
formDiv.animate([
    { height: 0},
    { height: 'auto'}
], {
    easing: 'ease-in-out',
    duration: 1000,
    fill: 'forwards'    // ensures menu stays open at end of animation
})
```

By contrast this

```
formDiv.animate({
    height: [0, '100%'],
    easing: 'ease-in-out'
}, {
    duration: 1000,
    fill: 'forwards'    // ensures menu stays open at end of animation
})
```

causes the div to expand immediately, but again with no smooth transition.

This does give a smooth transition, but requires a carefully chosen value to replace '300px' and is precisely what I want to avoid.

```
formDiv.animate([
    { "height": '0px', offset: 0},
    { "height": '300px', offset: 1}
], {
    duration: 1000,
    iterations: 1,
    fill: 'forwards'    // ensure form stays open at end of animation
})
```

Comment: 'auto' cannot be a value for reasons I can't explain or recall at the moment.

Comment: Ok, but `{ height: 100}` leads to an error about partial keyframes

Comment: That value is invalid cause you don't have units set, such as px.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not directly possible to do this with Web Animations or CSS animations/transitions yet. That is because CSS does not have a means to represent an intermediate state between an 'auto' length and a fixed length. The proposal to fix this involves allowing 'auto' inside `calc()`, e.g. `calc(auto + 36px)`. You can follow the progress of this development on the [CSS Transitions Github issue](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/626).

In the interim, many people have been able to work around this by animating `max-height` instead. For example, if you expect your 'auto' height to be somewhere between 300px and 600px, then you could leave `height` as 'auto', and animate `max-height` from '0' to '700px'. It's not perfect, but for a short animation it's often close enough.

Alternatively, one could set the height to `auto`, get the used value of the height using `getComputedStyle`, and, supposing it returned `375px`, create an animation from, `height: '0'` to `height: '375px'`. If you do not specify a `fill` on the animation then when it completes, the computed value of the height will switch from `height: 375px` to `height: auto` (which should make no visual difference but mean that the element's height responds to future changes in the content size).

Regarding the error about partial keyframes, that is a short-term issue where both Firefox and Chrome have not shipped support for omitting the first or last keyframe. Both Firefox and Chrome have implemented this feature and it should ship this year, however, it still won't fix this issue until `auto` is permitted in `calc()`.

**Update 22 May** with (completely untested) code samples as requested:

```
// Option 1: Use max-height
formDiv.animate(
  { maxHeight: ['0', '700px'] },
  { easing: 'ease-in-out', duration: 1000 }
);

// Option 2: Use used height
//
// (Beware, flushes layout initially so will probably not be very performant.)
formDiv.style.height = 'auto';
const finalHeight = getComputedStyle(formDiv).height;
formDiv.style.height = '0';
formDiv.animate(
  { height: ['0', finalHeight] },
  { easing: 'ease-in-out', duration: 1000 }
);
```

Of course if you don't actually have anything below the div you might be able to
get away with a transform animation which will definitely be the most
performant.

```
// Option 3: Use scale-y transform
formDiv.style.transformOrigin = '50% 0%';
formDiv.animate(
  { transform: ['scaleY(0)', 'scaleY(1)'] },
  { easing: 'ease-in-out', duration: 1000 }
);
```

Comment: Hey, could you add a code sample of how you would implement this? Thank you.

Answer (score -4):

If height is not mandatory you can try giving padding to the div.

```
@keyframes example {
   from{padding:0px;}
    to{padding: 50px;}
}
```

Vote up if it was help full.

Comment: I don't believe this will scale well